# My Python else: statement is read as invalid syntax

Tags: python, if-statement, syntax

(THIS IS WORK IN PROGRESS)
Hello, I am following a Python course called "Code Academy", and I am making a English to PygLatin Translator. When I compile my code I get an error message saying

```
File "python", line 8
    else:
       ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax
```

Any Help will be highly appreciated :), Here is my code.

```
pyg = 'ay'
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
first = word[0]
print original
else:
print 'empty'
```

Answer (score 3):

Your indentation is wrong.  These three lines:

```
first = word[0]

print original

print 'empty'
```

need to be indented one level:

```
pyg = 'ay'
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    print original
else:
    print 'empty'
```

Remember that indentation is important in Python.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this should be the answer or a comment, but your formatting is messed up which may be why you're having issues.

Remember that whitespace is important in Python. It looks like you've unindented partway through your `if` block, so your `else` is coming in the middle of nowhere (to the interpreter).

```
pyg = 'ay'
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    word = original.lower() # entered if block
first = word[0] # exited if block
print original
else: # else?? else what, there's no if!!!
print 'empty' # and what's more there's nothing IN the else block, this line is unindented
```

I'm going to guess at your meaning here, but the interpreter won't. My guess is that you meant to write:

```
pyg = 'ay'
original = raw_input('Enter a word:')
if len(original) > 0 and original.isalpha():
    # if this condition is true, then do...
    word = original.lower()
    first = word[0]
    print original
else:
    # if that condition up there ISN'T true, do...
    print 'empty'
```